Pandas - How to group the first level after swaplevel()
I have a multiindex df like this:

After I use swaplevel(axis=1), it looks like this:

How can I group the first level columns so that it would look like the first df?

This is actually just how the data is displayed in jupyter notebooks. If you do df.columns you will see that all the data is still there. To get a similar view, try df.sort_index(level=0,axis=1)
